# Style for setting mouse click or double-click handled

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to set a mouse click or double-click handled in a WPF style so that double-clicking on the control with the style will never bubble?

i.e.

```
<Setter Property="MouseDoubleClickHandled" Value="True">
```

I was hoping there's a way to do it without having to use a handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, there is no "XAML" way to do it. 
However, handler is not nice. It's not reusable. 
I would create myself an [Attached behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)

And hook up MouseButtonDown/MouseButtonDoubelClick event and use e.Handled=true. This way it will be reusable in different places.

You can also wrap your content into "Button" class. As far I know, Button class will mark your MouseClick&MouseDoubleClick events as handled automatically.

And you could also try to re-register specific event with RoutingStrategy.Direct <= okay this version does not work, as indicated here: [Microsoft help forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/104aa671-aafe-46cd-9536-88386b7f66e1)

Comment: Attached behaviour is a great idea. I always forget about that feature. I'll implement it that way. Thanks a lot.